# PDF processing by PDFBox app jar

Tags: python, performance, pdf

I want to convert a large PDF file into individual text files with PDFBox using Python. This code takes lot of time to convert a PDF containing 1000 pages.

Is there anything I can do to improve it?

I cannot use any other library. My other code (Python - parsing of obtained text) works best with output of PDFBox.

```
import PyPDF2
import sys
import os
import subprocess

pdfFileObj = open('cpdf.pdf', 'rb')
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)
tot = pdfReader.numPages
for i in range(1, tot+1):
    i = str(i)
    ffi = "out\\" + i + "-extracted.txt"
    command = "java -jar" + " " + "pdfbox-app-2.0.2.jar" + " " + "ExtractText" + " " + "cpdf.pdf" + " " + ffi + " " + "-startPage" + " " + i + " " + "-endPage" + " " + i
    subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)
    print('Completed ' + str(i))
```

On the other hand, when I do this, it takes 10 seconds:

```
import subprocess

command = "java -jar pdfbox-app-2.0.2.jar ExtractText cpdf.pdf  out.txt -startPage 1 -endPage 3158"

subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use `with..as` to open a file to make sure it is closed again, even if your program is interrupted:

```
with open('cpdf.pdf', 'rb') as pdfFileObj:
    ...
```

If your mode was only `r`, it could be omitted, as it is the default, however since the file is binary, we need `'rb'` here.

Building your command can be greatly simplified using `format`, leaving out the slow string additions:

```
command = "java -jar pdfbox-app-2.0.2.jar ExtractText cpdf.pdf {0} -startPage {1} -endPage {1}".format(ffi, i)
```

Pull the `command` variable out of the loop and make it a constant.

Get rid of the intermediate variable `ffi` (which is also a very bad variable name).

Choose better variable names, like `page`, instead of `i`.

Follow [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for variable names, use `lower_case`, not `camelCase`.

Make the file name a variable (allows passing it in via `sys.argv` or similar at some point).

Use `format`'s awesome features of replacing named place-holders and `locals()` to get a dictionary of locally defined variables. Use dictionary unpacking (`**dict`) to connect the two.

If you are using python 2.x (which does not seem to be the case, judging from your `print()`), use `xrange` instead of `range` to avoid building a list with 1000 elements before iterating and build a generator instead.

Final code:

```
import sys
import PyPDF2
import subprocess

COMMAND = "java -jar pdfbox-app-2.0.2.jar ExtractText {file_name} out\\{page}-extracted.txt -startPage {page} -endPage {page}"

file_name = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) == 2 else "cpdf.pdf"
with open(file_name, "rb") as pdf_file:
    pages = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf_file).numPages

for page in range(1, pages + 1):
    subprocess.check_output(COMMAND.format(**locals()), shell=True)
    print('Completed {}'.format(page))
```

Alternatively, saving the `pdf_reader.numPage` calls to `locals()`:

```
subprocess.check_output(COMMAND.format(page=page, file_name=file_name), shell=True)
```

If the code were longer I would put it into a function. In that case `COMMAND` should be defined inside that function, because local variable lookup is faster than global variable lookup.

With functions:

```
import sys
import PyPDF2
import subprocess


def run(file_name, page):
    command = "java -jar pdfbox-app-2.0.2.jar ExtractText {file_name} out\\{page}-extracted.txt -startPage {page} -endPage {page}"
    return subprocess.check_output(command.format(page=page, file_name=file_name), shell=True)


def number_of_pages(file_name):
    with open(file_name, "rb") as pdf_file:
        return PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf_file).numPages

if __name__ == "__main__":
    file_name = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) == 2 else "cpdf.pdf"
    pages = number_of_pages(file_name)

    for page in range(1, pages + 1):
        run(file_name, page)
        print('Completed {}'.format(page))
```

**Regarding your timing:** It is probably slow because you are repeatedly starting the java program, accumulating initialization times. Maybe you can split the text obtained from the combined command somehow?

Comment: I don't understand why we need to use **locals() let me understand it.

Comment: We don't **need** to use `locals()` (see alternative). What it does is giving you a dictionary back with the names of (in that scope) defined variables and their values. This dictionary will look like this: `{"file_name": "cpdf.pdf", "page": 1, ...}`. Where these two are actually the names we need to format our string correctly. The other variables are not needed and `format` discards the keywords it does not need.

Comment: There is really too much to learn before asking questions to code review. Thanks for the great efforts to explain. I learned a lot.

Comment: Have a look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals and https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language for some more details. But yes, there is a lot to learn :)